# No me cambia el tamaño de la imagen en una tabla

Tags: php, html, css

Quiero edit el tamaño de una imagen, y alinearla con el respectivo texto, pero en cambio, cuando le asigno un `width` y un `height` en vez de cambiar el tamaño según se le ha asignado, se desplaza.

**Sin asignarle un `width` `height`**

[image: sin width height]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Family</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./.style.css">
   <script src="./.sorttable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 <h1>FAMILY</h1>

 <table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nombre Fichero <br>
   <span class="ingles">Filename</span></th>
   <th>Tipo <br>
   <span class="ingles">Type</span></th>
   <th>Tamaño <br>
   <span class="ingles">Size</span></th>
   <th>Fecha de modificación <br>
   <span class="ingles">Modification Date</span></th>
  </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
<?php
 // Adds pretty filesizes
 function pretty_filesize($file) {
  $size=filesize($file);
  if($size<1024){$size=$size." Bytes";}
  elseif(($size<1048576)&&($size>1023)){$size=round($size/1024, 1)." KB";}
  elseif(($size<1073741824)&&($size>1048575)){$size=round($size/1048576, 1)." MB";}
  else{$size=round($size/1073741824, 1)." GB";}
  return $size;
 }
 
 // Checks to see if veiwing hidden files is enabled
 if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
 {$hide="";
  $ahref="./";
  $atext="Hide";}
 else
 {$hide=".";
  $ahref="./?hidden";
  $atext="";}

  // Opens directory
  $myDirectory=opendir(".");

 // Gets each entry
 while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[]=$entryName;
 }

 // Closes directory
 closedir($myDirectory);

 // Counts elements in array
 $indexCount=count($dirArray);

 // Sorts files
 sort($dirArray);

 // Loops through the array of files
 for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

 // Decides if hidden files should be displayed, based on query above.
     if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1)!=$hide) {

 // Resets Variables
  $favicon="";
  $class="file";

 // Gets File Names
  $name=$dirArray[$index];
  $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

 // Gets Date Modified
  $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
  $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));


 // Separates directories, and performs operations on those directories
  if(is_dir($dirArray[$index]))
  {
    $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;";
    $size="&lt;Directory&gt;";
    $sizekey="0";
    $class="dir";

   // Gets favicon.ico, and displays it, only if it exists.
    if(file_exists("$namehref/favicon.ico"))
     {
      $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/favicon.ico);'";
      $extn="&lt;Website&gt;";
     }

   // Cleans up . and .. directories
    if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;"; $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/.favicon.ico);'";}
    if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}
  }

 // File-only operations
  else{
   // Gets file extension
   $extn=pathinfo($dirArray[$index], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   // Gets and cleans up file size
    $size=pretty_filesize($dirArray[$index]);
    $sizekey=filesize($dirArray[$index]);
  }

   $nombre_directorio = $name;

   $url_imagen = '';

   switch($nombre_directorio) {
   case 'prueba1':
   $url_imagen = './.LGYTL_LOGO.png'; break;

   case 'prueba2':
   $url_imagen = './.cocacola.png'; break;
   case 'prueba3':
   $url_imagen = './.LGYTL_LOGO.png'; break;
   } 

 // Output
  echo("
  <tr class='$class'>
   <td><img src='" .$url_imagen. "'><a href='./$namehref' class='imagen_directorio'>$name</a></td>
   <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
  </tr>");
    }
 }
 
 ?>



     </tbody>
 </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que se muestra en el navegador:

```css
body {
 color: #FF0000;
 font: 14px Sans-Serif;
 padding: 50px;
 background: #eee;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 12px 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: strong;
}

.ingles {
 color: black;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 12px 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 17px;
}

.imagenICO {
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
 float: right;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo {
 width: 200px;
 height: 81px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 40px;
}

#container {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position: relative;
 background: white; 
}

table {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

th {
 background-color: #FF0000 ;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}

th small {
 font-size: 9px; 
 color: black;
}

td, th {
 text-align: left;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
/*
Cambia color de letra
*/
td a {
 color: black;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 font-size: 13px;
}
th a {
 padding-left: 0;
 color: #FFE800;
}

td:first-of-type a {
 background: url(./.images/file.png) no-repeat 10px 50%;
 padding-left: 35px;
}
th:first-of-type {
 padding-left: 35px;
}

td:not(:first-of-type) a {
 background-image: none !important;
} 

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

tr:hover td {
 background-color:#DF2727;
}

tr:hover td a {
 color: #FFF;
}

.imagen_directorio{
 float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}



/* icons for file types (icons by famfamfam) */

/* images */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".jpg"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".png"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".gif"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".svg"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".jpeg"]
{background-image: url(./.images/image.png);}

/* zips */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".zip"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/zip.png);}

/* css */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".css"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/css.png);}

/* docs */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".doc"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".docx"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".ppt"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".pptx"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".pps"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".ppsx"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".xls"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".xlsx"]
{background-image: url(./.images/office.png)}

/* videos */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".avi"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".wmv"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".mp4"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".mov"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".m4a"]
{background-image: url(./.images/video.png);}

/* audio */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".mp3"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".ogg"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".aac"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".wma"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/audio.png);}

/* web pages */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".html"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".htm"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".xml"]
{background-image: url(./.images/xml.png);}

table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".php"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/php.png);}

table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".js"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/script.png);}

/* directories */
table tr.dir td:first-of-type a
{background-image: url(./.images/folder.png);}


img {
  width:100px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nombre Fichero <br>
   <span class="ingles">Filename</span></th>
   <th>Tipo <br>
   <span class="ingles">Type</span></th>
   <th>Tamaño <br>
   <span class="ingles">Size</span></th>
   <th>Fecha de modificación <br>
   <span class="ingles">Modification Date</span></th>
  </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

  <tr class="dir">
   
   <td><img src="https://applesitges.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Toshiba-Logo-256x256.png"><a href="./prueba1" class="imagen_directorio">prueba1</a></td><td><a href="./prueba1">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="0"><a href="./prueba1">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="20200227082634"><a href="./prueba1">Feb 27 2020 8:26 AM</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dir">
   <td><img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/paypal-5-226456.png"><a href="./prueba2" class="imagen_directorio">prueba2</a></td>
   <td><a href="./prueba2">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="0"><a href="./prueba2">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="20200227082637"><a href="./prueba2">Feb 27 2020 8:26 AM</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dir">
   <td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/0U4udERPJf7RGa4-am2mzS7tUagiqv6Aw00-oyTz11L3ES1YAZ7DeqX-3TESHNI6U1PNNrZhChp2jnLptAcdNtwAHZ8fjUryl175KuckBdNomMqFg3q3cMxHxQNgk5dNinap2hSnyzd3SHVfVE5pMgrEskk1CkeJVK4"><a href="./prueba3" class="imagen_directorio">prueba3</a></td>
   <td><a href="./prueba3">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="0"><a href="./prueba3">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="20200227082640"><a href="./prueba3">Feb 27 2020 8:26 AM</a></td>
  </tr>


     </tbody>
 <tfoot></tfoot></table>
```

Y sale de esta forma en el navegador, desplazándose y comiéndose parte del texto:

[image: con width height]

Y el objetivo es que quede parecido a esto:

[image: objetivo]

He probado con todos los tipos de `display`, con todos los `position`, con `text-align`, `align-items` y nada. No cambia, y si cambia, no es como debe.

No sé qué debería estar cambiando para que me haga caso... Porque no creo que sea porque esté con código php, o quizá sí, no sé. En ese caso, ¿cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: No, a lo que me refiero es a que edites el `html` desde el navegador para que te deje copiarlo y así lo pegas en la pregunta con la estructura ya generada de los `tr` que te ha generado el bucle `for` de `php`. Lo puedes hacer como se indica [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examinar_y_editar_HTML#Editar_HTML), si usas chrome es exactamente igual. También puedes copiar directamente el elemento table. (Voy eliminando comentarios para que no se alargue esto.)

Comment: Ahora creo que es a lo que te referías. He añadido url de logos de internet para que se vea mejor cómo es la imagen, y cómo no se redimensiona aunque lo indique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que 2 elementos compartan la misma cabecera puedes hacer que el `th` de `filename` ocupe 2 columnas y después separar el contenido en 2 columnas.

Como sería la estructura:

```
_____________________________________________________
|___________________|__________|__________|__________|
|_________|_________|__________|__________|__________|
|_________|_________|__________|__________|__________|
|_________|_________|__________|__________|__________|
```

Colspan:

```
<th colspan="2">Nombre Fichero <br><span class="ingles">Filename</span></th>
```

Nota: he cambiado el orden de los `td` de la primera columna para que salgan en el orden que muestras en el ejemplo.

```
<tr class="dir">
    <td>
        <a href="./prueba1" class="imagen_directorio">prueba1</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="https://applesitges.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Toshiba-Logo-256x256.png">
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="./prueba1">&lt;Directory&gt;</a>
    </td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="0">
        <a href="./prueba1">&lt;Directory&gt;</a>
    </td>
    <td sorttable_customkey="20200227082634">
        <a href="./prueba1">Feb 27 2020 8:26 AM</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

**[Snippet] Solo cambios en el HTML:**

```css
body {
 color: #FF0000;
 font: 14px Sans-Serif;
 padding: 50px;
 background: #eee;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 12px 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: strong;
}

.ingles {
 color: black;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 12px 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 17px;
}

.imagenICO {
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
 float: right;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.logo {
 width: 200px;
 height: 81px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 40px;
}

#container {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position: relative;
 background: white; 
}

table {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

th {
 background-color: #FF0000 ;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}

th small {
 font-size: 9px; 
 color: black;
}

td, th {
 text-align: left;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
/*
Cambia color de letra
*/
td a {
 color: black;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 font-size: 13px;
}
th a {
 padding-left: 0;
 color: #FFE800;
}

td:first-of-type a {
 background: url(./.images/file.png) no-repeat 10px 50%;
 padding-left: 35px;
}
th:first-of-type {
 padding-left: 35px;
}

td:not(:first-of-type) a {
 background-image: none !important;
} 

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

tr:hover td {
 background-color:#DF2727;
}

tr:hover td a {
 color: #FFF;
}

.imagen_directorio{
 float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
}



/* icons for file types (icons by famfamfam) */

/* images */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".jpg"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".png"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".gif"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".svg"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".jpeg"]
{background-image: url(./.images/image.png);}

/* zips */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".zip"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/zip.png);}

/* css */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".css"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/css.png);}

/* docs */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".doc"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".docx"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".ppt"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".pptx"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".pps"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".ppsx"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".xls"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".xlsx"]
{background-image: url(./.images/office.png)}

/* videos */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".avi"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".wmv"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".mp4"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".mov"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".m4a"]
{background-image: url(./.images/video.png);}

/* audio */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".mp3"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".ogg"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".aac"], 
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".wma"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/audio.png);}

/* web pages */
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".html"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".htm"],
table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".xml"]
{background-image: url(./.images/xml.png);}

table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".php"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/php.png);}

table tr td:first-of-type a[href$=".js"] 
{background-image: url(./.images/script.png);}

/* directories */
table tr.dir td:first-of-type a
{background-image: url(./.images/folder.png);}


img {
  width:100px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th colspan="2">Nombre Fichero <br>
   <span class="ingles">Filename</span></th>
   <th>Tipo <br>
   <span class="ingles">Type</span></th>
   <th>Tamaño <br>
   <span class="ingles">Size</span></th>
   <th>Fecha de modificación <br>
   <span class="ingles">Modification Date</span></th>
  </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

  <tr class="dir">
   <td><a href="./prueba1" class="imagen_directorio">prueba1</a></td>
   <td><img src="https://applesitges.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Toshiba-Logo-256x256.png"></td>
      <td><a href="./prueba1">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="0"><a href="./prueba1">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="20200227082634"><a href="./prueba1">Feb 27 2020 8:26 AM</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dir">
      <td><a href="./prueba2" class="imagen_directorio">prueba2</a></td>
   <td><img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/paypal-5-226456.png"></td>
   <td><a href="./prueba2">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="0"><a href="./prueba2">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="20200227082637"><a href="./prueba2">Feb 27 2020 8:26 AM</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="dir">
      <td><a href="./prueba3" class="imagen_directorio">prueba3</a></td>
   <td><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/0U4udERPJf7RGa4-am2mzS7tUagiqv6Aw00-oyTz11L3ES1YAZ7DeqX-3TESHNI6U1PNNrZhChp2jnLptAcdNtwAHZ8fjUryl175KuckBdNomMqFg3q3cMxHxQNgk5dNinap2hSnyzd3SHVfVE5pMgrEskk1CkeJVK4"></td>
   <td><a href="./prueba3">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="0"><a href="./prueba3">&lt;Directory&gt;</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey="20200227082640"><a href="./prueba3">Feb 27 2020 8:26 AM</a></td>
  </tr>


     </tbody>
 <tfoot></tfoot></table>
```